# SOLR 4.0: Get unique LONG fields in requestHandler code

Tags: solr, requesthandler

I am writing a request handler for SOLR 4.0 and i am trying to get all unique values of a field of type `tlong` (field is indexed of course).

Whenever i try to get all unique terms for a tstring field i can simply use the following code:

```
DocTermsIndex sourceIndex=FieldCache.DEFAULT.getTermsIndex(searcher.getAtomicReader(), "txtField")      
TermsEnum terms=sourceIndex.getTermsEnum()
```

Then i can iterate over all unique terms, execute `utf8ToString()` on every term and it is working fine.

When i try to do the same for a `tlong` field i get garbled results - number of terms returned is different from the number of unique values and the values themselves do not represent `Long` in any way (different value lengths etc..).

Is there another way of obtaining a list of unique values for a `tlong` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found it out. If anyone is interested: longs seem to use different type of encoding in Solr 4.0, so we can approach them as ordinary strings as in the code above but later we have to use a different parser to convert term value to long:

```
 FieldCache.NUMERIC_UTILS_LONG_PARSER.parseLong(term)
```

It seems to throw an exception when no more elements are present. As for now it is working fine.